# Browsersync causes "Refused to execute inline script ... " error in SPA, if route in not root

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router, browser-sync

I got the following error in my Vue SPA:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security 
Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, 
a hash ('sha256-KpHv3zgivMSB4dPnfYfqMt2lBibsYvM36EdoBBAsfbM='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') 
is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, 
so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

This error caused by [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/):

[image]

First, this error occurs only if browser has been reloaded by browsersync in non-root route. For example, this error occurs in `http://localhost:3001/sign-in`, but never occurs in `http://localhost:3001`.

Next, this error occurs only in SPA, but never occurs in normal website (multiple pages, no manipulations with HTML5 history). So, I suppose, `vue-router` is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hypothesis about the cause is the BrowserSync was wrong. The cause is my past incomprehension how front-end routing works. Let's see what's going on in [history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) of **vue-router**:

1. Once building complete, new tab in browser with route "/" will open.
2. Vue-router generates the routes including `/sign-in`.
3. When we go to non-root page, e. g. to `http://localhost:3000/sign-in`
4. If we make corrections in code, the project will be re-built.
5. Browser-sync will reload the page `http://localhost:3000/sign-in`. But Browser Sync does not know what he must to return for `http://localhost:3000/sign-in` route! It's the static server, it knows only `http://localhost:3000/` and can return files relative to directory respective to `http://localhost:3000`. There is no file `sign-in`, so it error will occur.

This routes like `sign-in` has been created by `vue-router` in `http://localhost:3000/` page during routing initialization, but this data will be lost on next browser reloading.

### Solutions

I am sure that more than 10 approaches exists (for various project building tools), but I am satisfied with hash mode on local development mode. To enable the history mode on production and/or testing mode, the [appropriate server setup required](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations). Most likely it's possible to setup the Browser Sync to redirect like `http://localhost:3000/sign_in` => `http://localhost:3000/`.

I don't use the tools like `create-vue-app`, but I suppose the Webpack pre-setted somehow to avoid above issue ([Webpack hot module replacement](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/)?).